# How can I obtain State level Investment in the US?

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request

How can I obtain investment level data by state in the US?

I want to analyse how Public investment vs Private Investment responded to TFP shocks on a state level, so I am looking for Gross Private Domestic Investments, Residential and Non Residential investments for each state.

Comment: Is this a data request? Are you looking for data on public or private investment?

Comment: What Bayesian said, and also: by “investments” do you mean financial investments, or investments in productive capital?

Comment: I am looking for Public and Private Investment for each state in the US

Comment: Can you clarify the request? What exactly are you looking for? It also helps if you give a little bit of background on what you want to do with this data. Otherwise the people here cannot provide more information than you could get by googleing " "investment states US".

Comment: @Bayesian I want to analyse how Public investment vs Private Investment responded to TFP shocks on a state level, so I am looking for Gross Private Domestic Investments, Residential and Non Residential investments for each state

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question that I think you should bring up to the US Census bureau.

I believe at one point they did explore how to come up with capital measures by state; however, nothing ever happened.    At this point and at the time of this posting the measurement of capital measures by state does not exist.  It would appear this would be the "Holy Grail" of economic measurement.

There may be some capital data on equipment and structures at the state level from the Survey of Manufactures data (ASM) from the census bureau but that would be for only one sector in the economy.

There have been some studies about state level investment but the data used for the analysis are mostly state shares from  aggregate US totals.  The ratio used to come up with these types shares usually comes from the researchers assumptions, which is the best practice available.

Below is an example of a report:

https://www.cbpp.org/research/state-budget-and-tax/its-time-for-states-to-invest-in-infrastructure

If there is capital data at the state level someone please post the source here.